# Quiero representar grandes valores en matplotlib.pyplot sin que se vea muy mal

Tags: python

Vale tengo un problema y es que a la hora de hacer un frame para representar unos valores con matplotlib.pyplot, la gráfica que me sale es muy fea la letra super pequeña todo super pegado, mi pregunta es alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que se mas bonito?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ciudades=(España,EEUU,Peru,Mexico,etc...) #Aqui guardo todos los paises que hay en el mundo.
Confirmados=(235.000,12,000,23.000,3400, etc...) #Ejemplos de casos confirmados
plt.subplot(131)
plt.bar(ciudades, casosConfirmados)
plt.show()
```

Mi codigo es mas largo y complejo, pero pongo la parte que quiero que salga bien.
A la hora de ejecutar el python le da como resultado le siguente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y claro esto es muy feo, alguien sabe algo.
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algunas ideas:

- No emplear solo un tercero de la figura cuando hay tantas barras. Emplear una figura más ancha.
- No poner todos los países, pero solo p.e. los 20 más llamativos. Tal vez crear múltiples diagramas.
- Girar los nombres del eje `x` en vertical (`plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')`).
- Asignar un color por grupo, p.e. por continente.
- Poner los ticks del eje `y` de forma automática. P.e. [`AutoLocator()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html).
- Utilizar una librería como [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) para mostrar [más información](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bar.html) al mover el ratón sobre una barra.
- ...

Comment: Muchas gracias Johan pero tus recomendaciones intentare aplicar todo eso GRACIAS!